# Including Port numbers in %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts File

Tags: sql, sql-server, migration, hosts

Is it possible to include port numbers in hosts file? Reason that I'm asking is because I have sites that I'm trying to migrate from one hosting server to another, and the sites are pointing to an old SQL server that uses the standard TCP/IP port (1433). On the new server, the SQL Server port is different, and I don't want to change the connection strings for these sites.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure an [alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445.aspx) in the SQL Configuration Management tool. Is designed to cover exactly this scenario.

Comment: This does not answer the main question: "Is it possible to include port numbers in hosts file?" otherwise, a good answer.

Answer (score 11):

This is not possible in the host file. DNS doesn't know anything about port numbers.

Comment: You are right, it is not possible because I've discovered that hosts files only acts as a pointer to a specific IP address and nothing else. I might go and do the SQL Alias option that Remus Rusanu has suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The hosts file translates host names to IP addresses (and vice-versa). You can't include port numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a router to do port forwarding at the new site, and—if not already routed through the router, then give the router's address as the new host.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone I definded mine as follows, in the hosts file:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  MyServer
```

The MyServer works on a specific port.

The when SQL Server 2005 management studio asks for 'server name' when creating a connection, I entered 'Myserver,1234' where 1234 was the port number.

Since it remembers them in a drop down for next time, this was good enough for me.